# Why does a ddply command take so long after the progress bar gets to 100?

Tags: r, bigdata, plyr

I have a data file with 10000 lines. The file contains blocks of 100 lines with a different factor in the first column, and I use ddply to process them. For example like this:

```
result.df = ddply(data.df, "V1", calc_stuff, .progress = "text")
message("done!")
```

It takes about one minute for the ddply progress bar to get to 100%. However then R does "something" for another 5-7 minutes before the next line in the script is processed (the message is printed in this example).

What is R doing in that time? Collecting the results in "result.df"? Can I speed that up somehow? I have many of these files to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ddply` takes the following approach:

1. Split up dataset.
2. Apply function to each component of the split
3. Combine the components into one big result data set

The progressbar probably deals with step 2, and states how far along it is in processing each of the chunks. Step 3. is what takes time in your case, and is not included in the progressbar.

To speed up your analysis, I would stop using `plyr` and start using `dplyr`. This is orders of magnitude faster than `plyr`, and the successor to `plyr`. See the [tutorial I wrote](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_dplyr.html) for some more information.

Your code example would boil down to something like:

```
results.df = data.df %>% group_by(V1) %>% calc_stuff()
```

Comment: I tried dplyr using the exact command you suggest, it was slower than ddply. I was surprised by this also, but now I'm thinking I only counted the ddply progress bar time to check, not the addtional time of your step 3. Will try again, thanks.

Comment: @ShellfishGene, the long duration might be rooted in your function `calc_stuff()`. For a simple (well implemented) function, 10k rows of data should finish in no time

Comment: The actual calculation takes some time, but is included in what Paul called step 2 above, step 3 actually takes much longer in my case (after ddply's progress bar is done).

Comment: `dplyr` is generally much faster, if you want more feedback you need to provide a more detailed reproducible example.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it's faster indeed, I don't know what I looked at before. Now I just have some problems with the details, your example does not give the same output as the ddply version. I need to use do(calc_stuff(.)) instead, then it works. However that version has the problem that it changes a column of "circular" objects that calc_stuff() returns back to numerical.
I'll firgure it out, if not I'll post a separate question...